# Major Version difference from staging to Production

Tags: 2007, content-deployment

I have a staging environment and a Production environment , where Content Deploymeent takes place from Source to Destination. In the staging environment one of the Pages has a Major version as 6.0 published version, but for the same page in Prod is 9.0 published version.

What ever i change in the source page it does not get reflected even after an incremental deployment. I suspect because there is a higher version already in the Prod

How do i rectify this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was one of a situation - the solution was bit against the conventions.

There was a webpart in the Prod environment and the webpart was not in staging environment.

No matter what we do in stage publish without the webpart after the content deployment the webpart still existed in the prod page

The last thing what i did was to delete the webpart in Prod - This was against the rule

And did a content deployment

Now both of them are synchronised